# angular UI-Bootstrap modal not binding with controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I create ng-template and bind it with controller and this template pass through ui-bootstrap modal.
code :-

```
vm.uploadFile = function () {
        var uploadModal = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'upload.html',
            bindToController: true,
            controller: 'modalCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'modalVm',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {

                }
            }
        });

        uploadModal.result.then(function (data) {

                data.uploadedBy = 'admin';
                data.fileName = data.name;
                vulGridService.dataStackForFile.unshift(data);
                vulGridService.gridApi.core.refresh();
            }, function () {
                console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            }
        );
    }

}
```

my template is below:-

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="upload.html">
<div class="">
    <form name="component" ng-submit="modalVm.upload()" novalidate>

        <h4 class="margin-null modal-padding bg-primary">Upload File</h4>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>File Type</label><br>
                <div class="select-drop-down-icon">
                    <select ng-model="modalVm.file.fileType"
                            name="fileType"
                            class=" cover-block input-field-styling"
                            ng-change="modalVm.checkFile()" required>
                        <option value="">Select File Extension</option>
                        <option value="Qualys">Qualys(.xml)</option>
                        <option value="Nessus">Nessus(.nessus)</option>
                        <option value="zip">.zip</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group bottom-spacing">
                <label>File To Upload</label><br>
                <div class="cover-block form-control padding-null">
                    <input class="border-null text-field-padding" ng-model="modalVm.file.name">
                    <!--<file-field ng-change="modalVm.checkFile(uploadFile.name)"-->
                                <!--class="btn btn-primary inline-view pull-right "-->
                                <!--ng-model="uploadFile">-->
                        <!--<i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
                        <!--Chose File-->
                    <!--</file-field>-->
                    <div class="btn btn-primary inline-view pull-right upload-field">
                        <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Chose File
                        <input grab-file-name get-file-name="modalVm.getFileName" type="file" class="upload">
                    </div>

                    <div class="top-space">
                        <span class="error-text" ng-show="modalVm.extension">
                            Please Select proper extension file
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                <button ng-disabled="modalVm.extension" type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-success sharp mar-right" aria-label="Close">Save
                </button>
                <button type="reset" ng-click="modalVm.cancel()" data-dismiss="modal"
                        class="btn btn-danger sharp mar-right" aria-label="Close">Cancel
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

modalCtrl

```
function modalCtrl($uibModalInstance, toastr, dateFactory, $scope) {

    var modalVm = this;

    modalVm.extension = false;

    console.log($scope);


    modalVm.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    modalVm.upload = function (data) {
        // data.uploadedOn = dateFactory.getDate();
        // $uibModalInstance.close(data);
        // toastr.success('File is Uploaded', 'success', {closeButton: true});
    };

    modalVm.checkFile = function (file, fileType) {
        console.log(file, fileType);
        if (file) {
            switch (fileType) {
                case 'Nessus':
                    var matchNessus = /[(a-z)(A-Z)(0-9^)]+.(nessus)/g;
                    if (matchNessus.test(file)) {
                        console.log('Nessus', file);
                        modalVm.extension = false;
                    } else {
                        modalVm.extension = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Qualys':
                    var matchQualys = /[(a-z)(A-Z)(0-9^)]+.(xml)/g;
                    if (matchQualys.test(file)) {
                        console.log('Qualys', file);
                        modalVm.extension = false;
                    } else {
                        modalVm.extension = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'zip':
                    var matchZip = /[(a-z)(A-Z)(0-9^)]+.(zip)/g;
                    if (matchZip.test(file)) {
                        console.log('zip', file);
                        modalVm.extension = false;
                    } else {
                        modalVm.extension = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    modalVm.extension = true;
                    break;
            }
        }


    };

    modalVm.getFileName = function (gotFileName) {
        console.log($scope.fileType);
        modalVm.fileName = gotFileName;
    };

}
```

In which input field not binding with the controller but the function is invoking, please give any hint or solution on it.

Comment: Where is your modalCtrl?

Comment: Please go though through it and one another doubt can we transfer scope of controller from where we include a directive?